# Launch from GUI vs terminal - different path environment variable on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, ubuntu, eclipse-fp

Environment:

- Ubuntu
- Eclipse with EclipseFP plugin http://eclipsefp.github.io/

When opening EclipseFP by double clicking in Nemo file manager a custom tool named `htfpp` used by EclipseFP is not found. Error message: `buildwrapper: could not execute: htfpp`

htfpp executable is located in `~/.cabal/bin` and `~/.cabal/bin` is added to $PATH in `.bashrc`

Opening a terminal, navigating to the EclipeFP folder `cd Software/EclipeFP` and opening it with `./eclipse` the plugin works correctly. This has the disadvantage that the terminal is kept open to keep EclipseFP open.

Writing a `.sh` script that does the above does not work though... it seems that when running the script from the GUI, Eclipse does not pick up the path correctly.

Opening the previous `.sh` shell from a terminal works though.

It seems this is related to the way Linux/Ubuntu/Cinnamon passes path environment variable to a running file from GUI vs terminal.

Any ideas how to open EclipseFP with the correct $PATH environment variable set using a shortcut and without leaving any terminal open while it is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a home relative path inside `/etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/opt/ghc/7.8.2/bin:.cabal-sandbox/bin:~/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

the fix was to use an absolute path instead (`/home/freeman/.cabal/bin` instead of `~/.cabal/bin`):

```
PATH="/opt/ghc/7.8.2/bin:/home/freeman/.cabal-sandbox/bin:/home/freeman/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

After setting this and doing a restart opening eclipse executable directly from the GUI or a shortcut works correctly.

Comment: That sort of path doesn't really belong in `/etc/environment` but rather in your users startup scripts (whichever are appropriate for the task in question. But yes, using `~` there was the problem as that wasn't expanding correctly. Did it even expand at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner: I don't really know if it was expanding, was just checking by wether EclipseFP worked correctly or not. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

if you set it in .profile it should be picked up by gnome, bash, sh and the forth.

Comment: this does not work either, sorry, should have mentioned I tried

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your GUI session since making that `PATH` change?

The process environment for things launched by your GUI launcher is the environment of the GUI launcher itself.

That environment was set when it was started.

Starting it again (after ensuring that the `PATH` modification is picked up by whatever starts your GUI session) should fix this problem.